# what happens on Arduino power-on, and how long does it all take?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, bootloader, time

Here's what I think happens and how long it takes (FIXME means I don't know).  I'd like to end up with solid max times for everything if possible.

- Power-on, input caps to the 328P begin charging and Vcc to the 328P rising
- From the time it first comes to life, internal 328P hardware holds an
  internal reset line low.
- Vcc to 328P climbs past the power-on reset voltage threshold V_pot, which has
  a maximum value of 1.6V (see the ATmega328P_datasheet_revision_DS40002061A.pdf
  Table 29-11).  For a 9V battery with a typical internal resistance of 2 ohms,
  the time constant with the ~100 uF of input capacitance on the Arduino
  is RC = (2 * 0.0001) = 0.0002 s.  So this normally happens pretty fast,
  but note that if additional loads are connected to the Arduino Vcc or Vin
  things might take longer.
- A reset timer on 328P begins running.  When it expires the internal reset
  line will be released.  How long this timer will run depends on fuse settings.
  For the default Arduino fuse settings the timer will run for about 65 ms.
  For a 3.3V Arduino variant the typical time will be slightly longer (~69 ms).
  See ATmega328P_datasheet_revision_DS40002061A.pdf Table 29-11 Chapter 9
  for details.
- The PD7 line of the ATMEGA16U2 chip on on the Arduino holds the external
  reset line low past the point in time at which the internal reset is released,
  which causes the EXTRF bit of the MCUSR register on 328P the 328P to end up
  set (indicating an external reset).  FIXME: does it actually work like this
  (hold it low longer)?  FIXME: How long exactly?
- The external reset is released by the ATMEGA16U2
- The bootloader on the 328P begins executing
- The bootloader examines the MCUSR and finds that EXTRF is set, but WDRF
  of MCUSR is not set.  It therefore quickly flashes the on-board LED several
  times and the attempts to download a new program over the serial line.
  This process takes about 1.6 s total.
- The download attempt terminates with a watchdog timer timeout and consequent
  watchdog timer reset.  The EXTRF bit of MCUSR remains set (it is sticky and
  is only cleared by a power-on reset or explicit 0 write).  Time: pretty quick
- The bootloader starts executing (again).  Time: pretty quick
- The bootloader examines the MCUSR and finds that the EXTRF and WDRF bits
  of the MCUSR are both set.  It interprets this to mean that the bootloader
  just executed and terminated due to a watchdog timeout, i.e. it decides that
  an upload attempt has already been made.  It therefore clears the WDRF flag
  (since it thinks it probably set it itself) and jumps to the start of the
  application flash instead of making an upload attempt.  Time: pretty quick
- All the setup code required to provide the C environment your main()
  program requires runs.  This includes for example copying global variable
  intial values from flash to RAM, etc.  Time: FIXME?
- main() begins executing.

Comment: Why not measure this yourself, for your specific setup?

Comment: I've made a shield that can turn a controlled arduino on only once in a while (so can operate years on battery).  It also supports wake due to a user signal line activity (it exposes it's own Vcc from low-Iq regulator for this circuitry), and it propagates this signal to controlled arduino once it's safely turned on.  I'm interested in the worst-case time from when one of these signals fires to when arduino is on and running user code that can see the propagated signal, including in cases when user cuts RESET EN on controlled Arduino and reprograms fuses for fast rising power.

Comment: Are there any reasons you have to use an Arduino for this?

Comment: The 16u2 doesn't hold the "reset" pin low. While the chips is still in pre-startup, all the output pins are High-Z. when running it [set the "reset" pin to HIGH (pull-up), and then to OUTPUT](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/firmwares/atmegaxxu2/arduino-usbserial/Arduino-usbserial.c#L154-L155). So the pin is never OUTPUT LOW. It's High-Z, then pull-up HIGH, then HIGH. Also the "reset" pin is not directly connected to the reset of the 328p, but via a 100nF capacitor.

Comment: If the line from the 16u2 isn't doing it how is the MCUSR EXTIF getting set on power on?  The bootloader always runs and attempts a download, so it's getting set somehow.  But I thought that a normal power-on of a 328P caused PORF to be set but not EXTIF.  I looked around for the actual code that's on the 16u2 but didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that is far far easier to measure than to try and calculate.

Here's an Arduino Uno R2 with a simple sketch that just turns on D2.  Green is the power (7V to the barrel jack) and yellow is D2.

[image]

As you can see it takes 1.544 seconds (according to the resolution of my oscilloscope which, over those time scales, isn't that great) before D2 is driven high.

The sketch is simply:

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: This is consistent with what I've measured with timer1 on my controller (~1.520 actually without Arduino environment setup whatever that consists of).  So this is a right number for stock arduino with stock optiboot (as of this writing anyway).  It would still be nice to know some of the particular numbers though for cases when the obvious arduino hacks are done.  I guess C (and Arduino wiring) environment setup is the big remaining unknown.