# Arduino filling serial buffer with nulls

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, string, processing-lang

I just wrote some code that just sends a string from Arduino to [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29).

Processing prints the string and displays the number of characters in the buffer...
After uploading the sketch to the Arduino and starting Processing for the first time, the serial buffer is initially filled with a few things (it turns out that these are nulls; 0 in ASCII). Why is this happening?

And this **mostly** happens after uploading and starting Processing **for the first time**. When I start Processing for the second time, the buffer is initially free as it should be. I am using a genuine Arduino Uno. I also tested on another Arduino and another laptop, but there is still the same problem. So it should not be a hardware problem.

**Arduino Code**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //delay(1000)
  Serial.println("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
}
```

**Processing Code**

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;

void setup() {
  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM3", 9600);
}

void draw() {
  if (myPort.available()>0) {
    println("Buffer:"+myPort.available());
    String string = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (string!=null) {
      println("String:"+string);
    }
  }
}
```

In the image is other code just to show that the buffer contains nulls.

[image]

Comment: Is is an Arduino or an ESP? (Because the latter prints some data on boot, using a different baud rate, IIRC: 76800. This MAY result in nulls if you try to read them using a different baud rate than they're sent in, but usually results in garbage.)

Comment: I am using an Arduino Uno.

Comment: Not able to replicate your problem here with 1.8.19, avr core 1.8.5, processing 4.0.1, windows 10 and official UNO. Are you using something like a CH340 based clone?

Comment: The Arduino that I got is genuine not a clone.

Comment: Have you tried this `myPort.bufferUntil(lf);` in `setup()`? https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_bufferUntil_.html

Comment: There are a lot of these kind of questions on Stack Overflow (though I haven't seen this particular problem). [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868857/arduino-processing-and-serial-communication). Many solutions include catching exceptions (in Processing). [A list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino+processing) of 347.

Comment: Does the Arduino restart when connected to?

Comment: [Timing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811026/how-do-i-get-arduino-to-communicate-with-processing/61777761#61777761) have been reported.

Comment: Provide versions numbers of everything involved like I did in explaining my attempt to replicate your problem.

Comment: versions are the same as yours.
Arduino 1.8.19,  Processing 4.0.1

Comment: What happens if you connect a 10 kOhm resistor from D1 to 5V?

Comment: If the problem is a matter of timing of the startup of the two microcontrollers on the Arduino Uno (e.g., the serial RX input is floating for some fraction of a second (or even more)), starting setup() with a pause of, say, 5 seconds, could alleviate the problem.

Comment: (On some Arduinos, e.g. [Arduino Leonardo](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-leonardo-with-headers), the external pull-up resistor would not work there as it is for the second serial (hardware) port.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen that idea is *part* of why I asked the question. However I've since confirmed that the firmware for the Xu2 chip on the official UNO does in fact enable its internal pullup.

Comment: I tried connecting D1 to 5V but nothing changed

Comment: @PeterMortensen the Problem is alleviated by adding a 5 seconds delay before Serial.println(), but this makes the program slow.

Comment: In my tests, the *only* way I've been able to get anything approaching your sample output on an official UNO R3 is by pulling D1 toward ground strongly enough to cancel out the effect of the XU2's internal pullup. Do you have **nothing** besides the USB cable attached to your board when you're testing this? What kind of environment are you running this in? Have you tried a different computer? Have you tried a different UNO? Do see the exact same NUL characters if you use RealTerm?

Comment: @timemage I have nothing else connected to the board. I am using Arduino IDE 1.8.19.
I already tried the same code on a another arduino with another Computer. But those nulls still there. The number of NULL characters differes every time I upload the sketch. It is **not** the same number everytime.

Comment: Well, keep adding details. I'm able to recreate your test scenario in as far as it has been described, where the current answer to "Why is this happening?" is "It isn't." or at least "It isn't here." If you new details or a picture or something, I'll look at those and see if I'm replicating your setup accurately.

Comment: Re *"by adding a 5 seconds delay before Serial.println(), but this makes the program slow."*: No, I meant at startup, in `setup()`: A delay, before any set up of the serial hardware, as the ***very first*** statement / call. The 5 seconds is a *very* conservative number. It can successively be cut in half until the minimum required (empirically found) time has been found. It may only be 30 ms. But start with a very long time.

Comment: @timemage: I don't understand it either. I have now measured on a genuine Arduino R3 (not a clone) with a very weak pull-down resistor (1 MΩ - measured to 1.02 MΩ). The RX line was not asserted high until about 5 ms after the RESET signal went high (I measured 5.3 ms from RESET signal reached 2.0 V till RX went high). But a very simple sketch where the very first action in setup() was to set D12 to output and then high took a whopping 1.5 seconds (I measured 1.56 seconds), about 300 times longer. The Arduino was powered through the USB cable (and connected to a Linux system).

Comment: I also verified the 1.5 seconds with a stopwatch, by setting D13 (LED) high immediately after D12. I measured about 1.8 seconds from power on till the LED lit up. With reaction time, about 0.3 seconds, 1.5 seconds is about right.

Comment: Is there a way for setup() to execute sooner?

Comment: Related: *[What happens on Arduino power-on, and how long does it all take?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79011/what-happens-on-arduino-power-on-and-how-long-does-it-all-take)*. 1.544 seconds was measured on an Arduino Uno R2. *[Start your Arduino instantly - no boot time without bootloader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsa5h2tVM9w)*

Comment: OK, I got it the wrong way around. Robot12, what is the exact startup sequence of the two systems, the Processing program and the Arduino, (incl. approximate timing)? For instance, is the Processing program running while the Arduino is being programmed? What do you actually do? Can you add the steps/the procedure to the question?

Comment: If connecting to the COM port from Processing results in a RESET on the Arduino then the TX line could be floating for a number of milliseconds.

Comment: Only the ***first*** COM port connect/open after power on of the Arduino results in a RESET (at least on Linux, using 'Screen' as the serial monitor), pulse width about 600 µsec if a 2.0 V threshold is used (but it is a ill-defined RESET signal, RC charge up on the rising edge). Thus the system ***has a state*** on which the observed behaviour *may* depend on: 1) Connected to once. 2) Connected to more than once.

Comment: Further, TX does not change during such a "soft" RESET by connection, only during power up. The timing during power up for TX is similar to RX: TX is asserted high 5.2 ms after RESET becomes 2.0 V.

Comment: Correction: "... ***has a state*** ...  1) Never connected to. 2) Connected to one or more times.

Comment: (And the "soft" RESET by connection actually has an effect: the D12 control signal is unasserted (input) for 1.51 seconds, as expected.)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm going to be able to follow all of what you've said above now. But regarding the part you addressed me about *"The RX line was not asserted high until about 5 ms after"*, the thing I was testing was the transceivers RX (AVR's TX) because that's what's in play here. And that *may* well float for 5ms during power-on of the transceiver. However transceiver is also not trying to receive anything during that time, so it hardly matters. I ignored the other direction for a number of reasons, most of it related to fact that the first example doesn't read anything at all on the AVR.

Comment: @Robot12: Did you make progress?

Comment: sorry for the delay responding. I just ignored these Nulls and kept working on my project.